# Sort YouTube Videos by time of upload

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have searched the web tirelessly and looked through the YouTube API, but I still can't seem to find a way in which to request videos from a specific channel which have been uploaded since a certain date-time.

Something along the lines of this:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=videoContent&channel=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&uploadedAfter=1421056357914

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is to get the [channel's uploads playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads), the do a playlistItems.list with it.

Though currently playlistItems.list doesn't support orderBy or uploadedAfter, [it's in the works](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6869).